# New orders not being shown on user dashboard

Tags: magento-1.8, dashboard, order-email, admin-user

Suddenly, new orders are not being shown in the user dashboard anymore, under "My orders" section. Altough, those orders are being registered in the admin panel.

Magento Version 1.8.1.

Comment: The magento version on this matter is  1.8.1.0

Comment: I don't find the question anymore, but I think I read in an answer, that only complete orders are shown. Did you just upgrade?

Comment: Hi Fabian. I have not upgraded anything. This problem just started to happen today.